# FFmpeg raw video size parameter

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am using libavformat in my library to read a stream of raw i420 images and transform them into an mp4 video. I've found CLI commands that perform this but since I am using the library in my program I need to reconstruct the same thing.

Currently the code that is having a problem is looking like this:

```
        const auto raw_format = av_find_input_format("rawvideo");
        if (raw_format == nullptr) {
            log->error("Could not find RAW input parser in FFmpeg");
            throw std::runtime_error("RAW not found");
        }

        _format_context->pb = _io_context.get();

        AVDictionary *input_options = nullptr;
        av_dict_set(&input_options, "framerate", std::to_string(fps).c_str(), 0);
        av_dict_set(&input_options, "pix_fmt", "yuv420p", 0);
        av_dict_set(&input_options, "s:v", fmt::format("{}x{}", width, height).c_str(), 0);
        av_dict_set(&input_options, "size", fmt::format("{}x{}", width, height).c_str(), 0);

        auto formatPtr = _format_context.get();
        auto res = avformat_open_input(&formatPtr, "(memory file)", raw_format, &input_options);
```

Finding the `rawvideo` is no problem, but it fails in `avformat_open_input` with the error: `[2019-11-03 15:03:22.953] [11599:11663] [ffmpeg] [error] Picture size 0x0 is invalid`

I assumed the sizes are something I can insert using the input options, since in the CLI version it is passed using `-s:v 1920x1080`, however this does not seem to be true.

Where do I have to specify the dimensions of my raw input stream?

Comment: It's `pixel_format`, and `video_size`.

Comment: If you add this as an answer I can accept it :). Do you happen to know if there is a reference for these options somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific options for the rawvideo demuxer are `pixel_format` and `video_size`. The FFmpeg CLI has the generic input options `-size` and `-pix_fmt` as shims.

Run `ffmpeg -h demuxer=rawvideo` to get a list of these options.

Via C API, see `av_opt_show2()`.